# draw x image text in arabic

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, pdfsharp

I am using the code blow to draw text on a image which i will be adding to PDF which is working fine when i am adding English text. I would like to know how i can do this and add Arabic text. when i step through the code i can clearly see that the sting 'txtModule' is holding the text in Arabic. currenlt it is changeing the text to ????

```
Dim page As PdfPage = document.AddPage
        page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape
        Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
        Dim XImage As XImage = XImage.FromFile("C:\Projects\CISIPR\currentPr\images\Certificate\prCertificate.jpg")
        gfx.DrawImage(XImage, 20, 20, 800, 564)

        Dim fontModule As New XFont("arial", 20, XFontStyle.Bold)



        ' Draw the Module text box

        gfx.DrawString(txtModule, fontModule, New PdfSharp.Drawing.XSolidBrush(PdfSharp.Drawing.XColor.FromArgb(103, 154, 165)), _
        New XRect(0, 10, page.Width.Point, page.Height.Point), XStringFormats.Center)
```

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the font "Bookman" may not **contain** characters for Arabic?

Comment: I have tried fonts that is the first thing i tried, i have tried arial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code here will work in converting the font so;

```
Dim options = New XPdfFontOptions(PdfFontEncoding.Unicode, PdfFontEmbedding.Always)
Dim fontModule As New XFont("arial", 20, XFontStyle.Bold, options)
```

Comment: I tried it out in C#, it displays Arabic correctly (though from left to right).

Answer (score 1):

You should get more than "????", but you have to enable Unicode. See this sample:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Unicode-sample.ashx

But there is a show stopper: PDFsharp does not (yet) support LTR and Arabic glyphs.
I don't know what this means. Maybe it is enough to reverse the string and select initial, middle, and final glyphs in your code, maybe you cannot get correct Arabic at all.